# Wordnet access using queries

Tags: nlp, sparql, wordnet

Has anyone seen a library to access Wordnet using some sort of query language? My idea is that there should be a way to write something like:

```
SELECT hypernyms(word, level)
WHERE word = 'art'
```

I've already consulted SharpNLP, but is not quite what I want. It's awesome, but not what I'm looking for. Should I use some query language, like SPARQL or some homemade dialect of SQL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run directly SPARQL queries over the Wordnet database from the following SPARQL the endpoint hosted by Talis at:

- http://api.talis.com/stores/wordnet/services/sparql (now discontinued)

There's an RDF version of Wordnet loaded in it. Also see [Wordnet 3.0 in RDF](http://semanticweb.cs.vu.nl/lod/wn30/). Having an RDF version of the Wordnet data allows you to directly use SPARQL to query it. I have just tested it a bit and you can run something like:

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
  ?s <http://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20/schema/hyponymOf> ?o
}
LIMIT 10
```

This query would get a small sample of hyponyms. If you want to get it from here and learn SPARQL I recommend you as a start the [Jena/ARQ SPARQL Tutorial](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/Tutorial/).

#### Edit

In another question, [exploratory SPARQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930246/exploratory-sparql-queries), you can see how to run Exploratory SPARQL queries to investigate the structure of a dataset behind a SPARQL endpoint.

Comment: According to [RobV's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581934/api-to-access-wordnet-using-sparql-or-php?noredirect=1#comment30794045_20581934), the Talis service has been discontinued.