# Import RDF data in SQL?

Tags: rdf, sparql

I am quite comfortable using `SQL` but having an impossible time understanding `SPARQL`. For starters, I don't even understand how to look at the structure of the data (in `MySQL` I would just do `describe <table name>`) so I can query the appropriate fields.

Is there a way for me to import an entire RDF dataset into respective tables in a MySQL database?

Barring that, is there a way to `SELECT *` from *all* the tables (or whatever the equivalent descriptor is) such that I can get all the output data into csv (and take it from there?)

The RDF dataset I am trying to query has a [SPARQL endpoint](http://rdf.myexperiment.org/sparql) and even a guide on [How to SPARQL](http://rdf.myexperiment.org/howtosparql) but I am having a hard time understanding it.

For example:

```
PREFIX meannot: <http://rdf.myexperiment.org/ontologies/annotations/>
PREFIX sioc: <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX mebase: <http://rdf.myexperiment.org/ontologies/base/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?annotator_name
WHERE {
  ?comment mebase:annotates <http://www.myexperiment.org/workflows/52> .
  ?comment rdf:type meannot:Comment .
  ?comment mebase:has-annotator ?annotator
  ?annotator sioc:name ?annotator_name
}
```

makes little sense to me. Why is there a period at the end of some of the WHERE statements but not others? and what does `?comment mebase:has-annotator ?annotator` mean in plain English? Select the annotators name where annotators name is the annotators name? huh?

I would be grateful for any resources that you could point me to.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Although SPARQL looks SQL like in its syntax how it functions is actually quite different which is the problem you and many others have when trying to learn it.

#### Pattern Matching

SPARQL is about triple pattern matching rather than selecting from tables like SQL.  Each set of three items in your example represents a triple pattern.  So for example:

```
?comment rdf:type meannot:Comment .
```

This tells the SPARQL processor to find any thing which has `rdf:type` of `meannot:Comment` i.e. **things which are of type comment**.  In this pattern `?comment` is a variable which acts like a wildcard, think of this as a field in SQL that you can select

If we add in additional triple pattern that uses a variable then we are asking the SPARQL processor to find all things which match all triple patterns, so:

```
?comment mebase:annotates <http://www.myexperiment.org/workflows/52> .
?comment rdf:type meannot:Comment .
```

This finds **things which are comments on a specific item**.
In SQL terms this would be like writing `SELECT commentID FROM COMMENTS WHERE itemID=1234` if that helps you understand it.

As we start adding in additional variables you can think of that as doing joins with other tables:

```
?comment mebase:annotates <http://www.myexperiment.org/workflows/52> .
?comment rdf:type meannot:Comment .
?comment mebase:has-annotator ?annotator .
```

This finds **things which are comments and the users that made them on a specific item**
It would be roughly equivalent to `SELECT commentID, userID FROM COMMENTS C INNER JOIN USERS U ON C.userID=U.userID WHERE itemID=1234` in SQL

#### Syntax Notes

As far as the syntax goes the `.` denotes the end of a triple pattern.
The fact that it is omitted in your example is actually an error on the part of the people publishing that how to guide.  I happen to work in one of the universities who are involved in the project so I have dropped a colleague a note asking them to fix this.

What you may also see in examples is the use of `;` at the end of a triple pattern.  These are shorthands for repeating the subject e.g.

```
?comment mebase:annotates <http://www.myexperiment.org/workflows/52> ;
         rdf:type meannot:Comment .
```

Means that you don't have to type out `?comment` again for the subsequent pattern.

Similarily `,` is used to repeat the subject and the predicate:

```
?comment rdf:type meannot:Comment , ex:Annotation .
```

Would mean that `?comment` and `rdf:type` are repeated, in plain english the above would be **things which are of type comment and of type annotation**

#### Discovering the data structure

RDF is not stored in tables since it is a schemaless data model, the closest thing to tables are named graphs which are just a way to logically group sets of triples together.

Take a look at this question on [exploratory SPARQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930246/exploratory-sparql-queries) for some suggestions on queries to try.

If you just want to select everything you can do `SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }` - beware that many endpoints will impose a limit on the number of results for one query so even if the endpoint has millions of triples behind it you may get only a few thousand back.  You can page through results using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` e.g.

```
SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000
SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 2000
# And so forth until you find no further results
```

If you just want to get all the data to trawl through try looking around on a site to see if they offer an *RDF dump* which will typically be a zipped archive with a bunch of RDF files in it.  This will let you look at the data locally

#### Putting RDF into SQL tables

There are systems that will let you store RDF in SQL based databases but take it from someone who's worked with a large variety of triple stores this is nowhere near as performant as using a native triple store.

You may be interested in [R2RML](http://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/) which is a new W3C standard (currently in early working draft) which defines a standard way to map relational data to RDF.  Some of their documentation may help you better understand the relationship between RDF/SPARQL and SQL

#### Tutorials

For a fuller tutorial I'd check out [SPARQL by Example](http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/2008/09/sparql-by-example/) which is by one of the authors of the SPARQL specification and is highly recommended

Comment: Thanks Rob for taking the time to write such a detailed reply while being patient with a n00b like me.

Comment: @Maiasaura Always happy to help, if you have more Semantic Web related questions you may find you get more answers by posting on http://answers.semanticweb.com

Answer (score 4):

You can use [RDF2X](https://github.com/Merck/rdf2x) to convert big RDF dumps to MySQL, PostgreSQL or other relational database. A simple alternative for smaller datasets is [rdf2rdb](https://github.com/michaelbrunnbauer/rdf2rdb).