# Java SPARQL Select query

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, jena, fuseki

I wrote a `SELECT` statement that returns me all data from the `fuseki-server`. My question is how I can get a list with all names available below the `o` column (see the attached image)?

[image]

For example, I need an array that will contain the following items:
`[Pavel Ionut, Cirstea Aurel, Test1]`

This is my `SELECT` statement, which should be changed to return only the `name` property ... but I did not use `SPARQL` before and any solution would help me a lot.

```
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(
        "http://localhost:3030/Date/query", "SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o}");
ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results);
qe.close();
System.out.println(results);
```

Comment: Please start with a SPARQL tutorial. It doesn't make sense that people provide you the query now without you understanding the *why* and *how* - next time you will need another query and have to ask here again. SPARQL is not difficult to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return the set of objects from all existing s-p-o triples use this SPARQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?o WHERE { ?s ?p ?o . }
```

To only get the names, try:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?n WHERE { ?s dc:name ?n . }
```

or just:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?n WHERE { ?s <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/name> ?n . }
```

The specification contains some good examples:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/

To iterate over the result set of the query above with Apache Jena Fuseki in Java, this might work:

```
while (results.hasNext()) {
    QuerySolution querySolution = results.next();
    RDFNode node = querySolution.get("n");
    String name = node.asLiteral().getString();
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I get only the names?

Comment: That works! Do you also know how can I loop through each name using Java?

Comment: @LauraCîrstea I currently can not test this in code, but maybe it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify what the same you queried in your query.
 More detail you can find here:

[exploratory SPARQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930246/exploratory-sparql-queries?rq=1)

Comment: Can you be more explicit, please?

Comment: here you can identify what the same you want
SELECT   ?s ?p ?o

Comment: and later from where:

Comment: SELECT    ?s ?p ?o
WHERE 
{
   
    ?Srule Answer:rule_s ?s.

    ?Prule Answer:rule_p ?p.
    ?Orule Answer:rule_o ?o.

}

Comment: "Person test" must be defined by " s "
"Pavel Ionut", etc must be defined by " o"

Comment: Ok, but how can I get all names, like "Pavel Ionut, Cirstea Aurel, Test1"