# Read RDF/XML file from website in Excel

Tags: excel, rdf, rdf-xml

I need to read a RDF/XML file from a website but haven't figured out how yet after reading some other posts and have no previous experience with such files.

Ideally I would convert [this file](http://www.bcn.cat/tercerlloc/serveis_socials.rdf) to be dealt with Excel as a bunch of data, can anyone guide me a hint with the file?

Comment: An rdf file is metadata. Parse the metadata or open it as an xml file.

Comment: You can read the RDF using Apache Jena and write it to Excel using Apache POI for example.

Comment: We don't know the programming language, but you should be able to search for RDF frameworks in the appropriate language, or not? Excel = CSV, thus, RDF to CSV/TSV which is trivial for e.g. N-Triples format

Comment: There are tools with which you can run SPARQL queries on RDF files. Then you can export the result as CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get a table of all triples in your file, using for example the Structured Data Sniffer, which is a browser extension. [This](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql/?default-graph-uri=&query=%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20*%0D%0AFROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.bcn.cat%2Ftercerlloc%2Fserveis_socials.rdf%3E%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%7D%20&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=0&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) would be the result. If you change "uri=&query=" with "uri=&q**txt**=", you'll enter edit mode. There you can choose CSV or another result format.

Yet, having the list of triples would not be a very useful result, so you need to explore your data. A good starting point would be to run

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?property
FROM <http://www.bcn.cat/tercerlloc/serveis_socials.rdf>
WHERE {
  ?s ?property ?o .
}
```

This will give you the list of properties, a subset of which you'd finally use as columns of your result table. Then you can run other [exploratory queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930246/exploratory-sparql-queries), until you get sufficient understanding of your data set.